# Common mode surges protection (IEC-61000-4-5)

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pcb, emc, emi-filtering

I have a problem with EMC testing. The test that fails is IEC61000-4-5 (surge), 2kV L-PE level. The design is quite old, but I need to maintain it as it is.
In my application, I have two independent PCB boards. They are connected in parallel to 230V.

For differential mode surges (L-N), we have MOV varistors, and devices pass the EMC testing. But when we are applying the common mode Surge pulses +/-2kV, we have a fail, because the relay on the secondary side, which is switching the 230V power supply to AC motor, is switching on/sticking somehow and starting the motor.

I am trying to analyze the whole circuit, but I have no ideas why it is happening. Both boards have a common mode choke, and Y capacitors are also on both boars.
I am attaching the simplified scheme of the situation. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: If the relay is switching on and, you haven't shown what hardware activates it, how do you expect anyone to figure this out without guessing. Also, when you say this: *I am attaching the simplified scheme of the situation.* that is usually a bad idea. Simplified schematics are quite often useless.

Comment: The PE-Capacitors and CMC do not much against surges (which are sort of slow). Please detail what is the relation of your secondary circuit and PE. Especially, how much capacitive coupling to PE do you have ? How much parasitic capacitance is there across your isolation transformers?